# perl regex, remove what is captured

Tags: regex, perl, match

I've successfully captured data with this:

```
/^.{144}(.{15}).{34}(.{1})/
```

which results in this:

```
TTGGCCCCCACTCTC T
```

I want to remove the same characters from the same locations. I tried a simple substitution:

```
s/^.{144}(.{15}).{34}(.{1})//
```

That removes everything described. How do I remove only (...)?

Comment: Capture other parts as well so to be able to replace the whole match with just the parts you want to keep: `s/^(.{144})(.{15})(.{34})(.)/$1$3/`.  Or, you can "drop" the first match (with `\K`) so you don't have to put it back in: `s/^(.{144})\K(.{15})(.{34})(.)/$3/`.  if you don't need the things you are removing (like to print them or store elsewhere) then omit their capturing parens -- they aren't needed in order to just match, `s/^.{144}\K.{15}(.{34})./$1/`

Comment: Docs: tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut), full reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). There are a few other pages as well

Comment: Still stuck. I need to determine the groups I want to keep before execution of any one pass, in this case $keep = "$1$3$5." But s/.../$keep/ results with the whole record being replaced by the literal. The data, groups, etc changes with every iteration. I can't know beforehand (nearly a million records) what I'll need. Lost.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  So, after you run the regex (the version where every group is captured by `()`), `$v =~ s/.../.../;`, you have the 144 chars in `$1` and next 15 in `$2` (and that's removed from `$v`) then 34 chars in `$3` then 1 char in `$4` (removed from `$v`).  Then, if you need the rest and add `(.+)` that's in `$5` (kept). You do with those what you need, and in the next iteration (of some loop I presume) it all happens anew with whatever new is in `$var`...  What's wrong in this story?

Comment: Hang on --- if you mean that you literally write `$keep = '$1$2$3'` and then use `$keep` in the regex (need single quotes there) ... can't do that.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: (since I won't be able to monitor this much longer I posted and asnwer assuming that the problem is what my previous comment states. please let me know...)

Comment: I want to keep the data in variables $1$2$3. The trouble is that I don't know what to keep until the data is evaluated. Instead of returning the data, /.../$keep/ returns the literal '$1$2$3.' The entire sequence of 400 letters is lost.

Comment: I want to keep the data in variables $1$2$3. The trouble is that I don't know what to keep until the data is evaluated. Instead of returning the data, /.../$keep/ returns the literal '$1$2$3.' The entire sequence of 400 letters is lost.

Comment: I don't understand this interface. I can't find the answers posted by others. I'm new here.

Comment: Okay. It seems the cleanest (if not most elegant) way is two create to patterns.

The list of deletions -- data I want to note:
/.{41}.{24}(\D{4}).{63}.{16}(\D{2}).{22}.{228}/

Data I want to keep:
/(.{41})(.{24})\D{4}(.{63})(.{16})\D{2}(.{22})(.{228})/

Answer (score 4):

Substitution works like

```perl
s/match/replace/
```

So it will replace youre complete "match" with "replace". If you want to keep part of your match, you must set references of the groups in the replacement string.

```perl
s/^.{144}(.{15}).{34}(.{1})//     # replace all with nothing
s/^.{144}(.{15}).{34}(.{1})/$1/   # replace all with group 1 (.{15}) -> not what you want
s/^(.{144}).{15}(.{34}).{1}/$1$2/ # keeps group 1 and 2 and removes ".{15}" between them and all at the end.
```

The last one you need.

Try [regex101](https://regex101.com/). There you can give a pattern and it shows you the groups. There is a debugger, too.

Comment: Thanks! The page was a big help in visualizing this. I grouped everything, including the last chunk with (.+). I kept what I needed with /$1$3$5/ and that deleted $2 and $4. Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: For visualizing of regexes I like https://www.debuggex.com/ too.

Answer (score 3):

The replacement side in the regex is substituted instead of everything that was matched (while there are ways to alter this to some extent), so you need to capture things intended to be kept as well, and put them back in the replacement side. Like

```
$var =~ s/^(.{144})(.{15})(.{34})(.)(.*)/$1$3$5/;
```

(the last capture was added in a comment)   or

```
$var =~ s/^(.{144})\K(.{15})(.{34})(.)(.*)/$3$5/;
```

Now the 15 chars and the single char are removed from `$var`, while you still have all of `$N` (1--5) available to work with as needed. (In the second version the `\K` **k**eeps all matches previous to it so that they are not getting replaced, and thus we don't need `$1` in the replacement side.)  Please see [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut) for details.

However, as a comment enlightens us, there is a problem with this: It is not known before runtime which groups need be kept!  So it could be 1,3,5 or perhaps 2 and 4 (or 7 and 11?).

What need be kept becomes known, and need be set, before the regex runs.

One way to do that: once the list of capture groups to keep is known store their indices in an array, then capture all matches into an array<sup>†</sup> and form the replacement and rewrite the string by hand

```
my @keep_idx = qw(0 2 4);  # indices of capture groups to keep

my @captures = $var =~ /^(.{144})(.{15})(.{34})(.)(.*)/;

# Rewrite the variable using only @keep_idx -indexed captures
$var = join '', grep { defined } @captures[@keep_idx];

# Use @captures as needed...
```

The code above simply filters by `grep` any possibly non-existent "captures" -- a pattern may allow for a variable number of capture groups (so there may not exist group #5 for example). But I'd rather check those `@captures` explicitly (were there as many as expected? were they all of the expected form? etc).

There are other ways to do this.<sup>‡</sup>

---

<sup>†</sup> In newer perls (from version 5.25.7) there is the `@{^CAPTURE}` [predefined variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#@%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D) with all captures, so one can run the match `$var =~ /.../;` and then use it.  No need to assign captures.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  I'd like to mention one way that may be tempting, and can be seen around, but is best avoided.

One *can* form a string for the replacement side and double-evaluate it, like so

```
my $keep = q($1.$3.$5);  # perl *code*, concatenating variables

$var =~ s/.../$keep/ee;  # DANGEROUS. Runs any code in $keep
```

Here the modifiers `/ee` evaluate the right-hand side, and in a way that exposes the program to evaluating *code* (in `$keep`) that may have been slipped to it. Search for this for more information but I'd say best don't use it where it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. I don't get how the comments work and kept fowling those up. I've decided that the cleanest (if not most elegant) way is to create two patterns. I'm keeping other solutions for future study. This is a different example,

The list of data I want to note, then delete:

```
/.{41}.{24}(\D{4}).{63}.{16}(\D{2}).{22}.{228}/
```

Data I want to keep:

```
/(.{41})(.{24})\D{4}(.{63})(.{16})\D{2}(.{22})(.{228})/
```

It's genetic data I'm working with. I need to note insertions then delete them to re-establish the original positions for alignment purposes.

If I understand correctly, I need to upvote this to close. An idiot as myself can only do what he can do. I'll try. :)

Comment: Sorry. I can't find "upvote." I haven't been on this site for several years.

Comment: One "upvote"s an answer by clicking on the grayed "arrow" to the left of the text, which is above the score, and one can vote on any and all answers; I suggest to always do that, upvote all answers that are useful to you.  You cannot upvote your own answer.  You "accept" one of the answers (the one which by your assessment best answers your question), by clicking on the grayed out check mark to the left of the text of that answer.  You _can_ accept your own answer, if that one best answers your question.